# Another installation is in progress

Tags: installer, windows-installer

Why I try to install any program I see "Another installation is in progress. You must complete that installation before continuing this one." error.

Googled the web and found that solution would be to delete 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\InProgress registry key and reboot. 
That didn't help me unfortunately. When I open "Services" mmc snapin it shows that "Windows Installer" service is "Started", but "Start/Stop/Pause/Restart" buttons are grayed (the interesting thing is that startup type = "Manual", so I don't really know how to explain that I already have 2 instances of msiexec.exe in memory and one instance is consuming 50Mb of memory.

Looks like there's a serious issue with my installer service - is there any way to fix it (please do mind - I can't install anything!)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Go grab the [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx).

You should be able to see the msiexec.exe service running, and if something is in the middle of installing you should see other msiexec.exe children processes. It would be best to allow them to finish, and maybe try to squeak your install in between.

I have seen it before where the .NET Runtime Optimization Service is constantly firing off ngen.exe using the installer service to generate optimized .net assemblies and never allows the installer to use anything else. You can try stopping that service to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked for malware?

The Windows intaller service is normally set to manual and  the buttons will be greyed until you change to Automatic.

Two instances of MSIEXEC running seems unusual. do you have AV software running?  Is it up to date?

Anything unusual in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\run ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but for those using Windows 10, you may not be able to see the msiexec process under processes but under Details. You can navigate there and end it.

Comment: Your answer is like a comment

Answer (score -1):

How to deal with "another msi installation already in progress" when all others hints didn't work :

In the registry, the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\InProgress will point to a file located under the C:\Windows\Installer directory with an IPI extension (something like f2345.ipi).
Note that removing the InProgess key even with the Rollback doesn't solve anything and the key will be recreated as it was by msiexec.

Opening this file with notepad or any text editor will show a lot of binary content but at some place you'll find some readable text :
...ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
3 0 8 9 9 8 1 9                                                 - 1 9 8 8 7 3 6 7 2 0                                           { 6 5 C C 0 4 0 7 - 4 C C 0 - 4 A C 7 - 9 5 2 E - 3 E E F C B A 6 0 2 A }                                                     0                                                               [ 1 ]
C : \ W i n d o w s \ I n s t a l l e r \ 6 9 6 f 0 . m s i

The information which is meaningful lies in this file which is the installer for the failed installation (which blocks the other installation).

Launching this installation (double clicking on the file) will lead to some options like install, repair or remove the product.
Try using one of them (repair first, as it should solve the problem, then remove) in order to properly end this aborted installation.

Answer (score -1):

You might have to restore windows from an earlier point. Under Advanced Startup Options, System Restore (accessible F3 key during boot, I think).

Answer (score -2):

This could be malware, as @DaveM states.

Have you tried to look into Task Manager whenever your setup is closed? Sometimes you see still somewhere a 'setup.exe'... Sometimes you can't get it away. This is called malware; worms; virusses; what not else.

I guess one of the only things you can do is what @DaveM said; or you're just going to reinstall Windows. If this does not even solve your problems; try thinking better; try thinking more secure; try thinking Mac.